# creating simple JS with PHP

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to recreate the JS below with PHP. The reason is that the numbered classes and values are actually IDs pulled from a mysql database. I have an area where say a report is creating, the code below shows and hides rules for that report. Since different reports have different rules, it shows and hides rules dependent on the grouping, determined in the code below as #rule_who.

When trying to recreate the following I was trying to use while loops however it got pretty ridiculous. Is there a more efficient way in JavaScript or AJAX to show and hide divs that would be better suited to using a large number of divs? The 2,3,4, and so on shouldn't be an incrementing number as it would rely on IDs and thus some numbers will disappear over time as reports are deleted.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
<script>
//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
   $(".2").hide();
   $(".3").hide();
   $(".4").hide();
        $('#rule_who').on('change', function () {

    if(this.value === "2"){
   $(".2").show();
   $(".3").hide();
   $(".4").hide();
    } else if(this.value === "3"){
   $(".2").hide();
   $(".3").show();
   $(".4").hide();
    } else if(this.value === "4"){
   $(".2").hide();
   $(".3").hide();
   $(".4").show();
    } else {
   $(".2").hide();
   $(".3").hide();
   $(".4").hide();
    }

});
});//]]>  

</script>
```

EDIT: Thanks everyone for the help.

What I ended up using was the following:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){

$("#rule_who").change(function() {
    $("div.specific_rules").hide();
    var targetId = $(this).val();

    console.log($(targetId).html());
    // show the new selected one
    $("#"+targetId).show();
});
});//]]>  

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do:

```
$('.' + this.value).show();
$('.' + this.value).siblings().hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this ([FIDDLE EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/U4PJ2/3/)):

```
$('.1, .2, .3').hide();    
 $(window).load(function(){
        $('#rule_who').on('change', function () {
           var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
                for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
                    if (elems[i].className != this.value) {
                        elems[i].style.display = 'none';
                    } else {
                        elems[i].style.display = 'block';
                    }
                }
        });
  });
```